# Read CSV file with Pandas: Regex delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I am facing an issue while trying to find the right regex expression for the read_csv delimiter.
My initial txt data looks something like this.

```
t = '''
[21.01.22, 07:32:11] text1
text2
[21.01.22, 07:34:18] text3
[21.01.22, 07:32:51] text4
text5
'''
```

I need to separate the rows by the newline and the square bracket expression, so that the desired outcome looks like this

```
column 1 | column2
[21.01.22, 07:32:11] | text1 text2
[21.01.22, 07:34:18] | text3
[21.01.22, 07:32:51] | text4 text5
```

The problem I am currently struggling to solve is that some lines contain strings without sqaure brackets. The text inside the square brackets is always of the same format: *[dd.mm.yy, hh:mm:ss]*

Can you please help me find the right regex expression for the delimiter parameter?

```
data = pd.read_csv('t.txt', delimiter=r"\[(..................)\]", header=None, engine="python")
```

Comment: can you update the example to add the line without the square brackets? Do you always have only 2 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sjjC54/1)):

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

t = """
[21.01.22, 07:32:11] text1
text2
[21.01.22, 07:34:18] text3
[21.01.22, 07:32:51] text4
text5
"""

df = pd.DataFrame(
    re.findall(r"^(\[[^]]+\])(.*?)(?=^\[|\Z)", t, flags=re.S | re.M),
    columns=["Column1", "Column2"],
)
df["Column2"] = df["Column2"].str.replace("\n", " ").str.strip()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                Column1      Column2
0  [21.01.22, 07:32:11]  text1 text2
1  [21.01.22, 07:34:18]        text3
2  [21.01.22, 07:32:51]  text4 text5
```

Comment: Apparently not all rows have the square brackets, so this wouldn't work (waiting for an example…)

Comment: @Andrej Kesely Thanks for your solution! Indeed it already looks very close to what I desire. The only problem is that I need to transform a txt file into the pandas dataframe and not the string as in my example. Can you please elaborate, how I could use same logic in the pd.read_csv statement (in delimiter parameter, I assume)?

Comment: @mozway Thank you also for your response. The lines without brackets in my initial example are representet as text2 & text5

Comment: I see, then this should work and I thought it would be more complicated ;)

Comment: use `with open('your_file.csv') as f: df = pd.DataFrame(re.findall(..., f.read(), ...)...)`

Comment: @ArtemKel Just read the contents of the log file to string and use `re.findall` as in my example.

Answer (score 0):

maynot be elegant, but seems to work

```
# readin the file
lines=''
with open("c:\csv2.txt") as fi:  
    line=fi.read()
    lines += line

#replace newline with space, so that we have a single string
lines=re.sub(r'(\n)+',' ', lines)

# add few delimiters to help split up the lines at set locations
# workaround: add | delimiter before [
lines=re.sub(r'( \[)+','|[', lines)

#workaround: add ; delimiter after ]
lines=re.sub(r'(\] )+','];', lines)

# create a dataframe by splitting on | delimiter
df1=pd.DataFrame(lines.split('|'))

# split again on ; delimiter and create new columns
df1[['column1','columns2']]= df1[0].str.split(";", expand=True) 

# drop the originally read-in column
df1.drop(columns=[0], inplace=True)
df1
```

```
    column1                 columns2
0   [21.01.22, 07:32:11]    text1 text2
1   [21.01.22, 07:34:18]    text3
2   [21.01.22, 07:32:51]    text4 text5
```